# Replace is not defined, but why?

Tags: javascript

can somebody tell me what is wrong?

**JS Code**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://www.google.com/complete/search?qu=chicken",
    success:function(data){

        var test_data = ''+data+''; // convert object to a string
        $('body').append(typeof(test_data));

        var test_data = replace.test_data(/[0-9]/,'X');
        $('body').append('<hr />'+test_data+' <hr />');

    },
    dataType:'jsonp',
    error:function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

**jsfiddle**
http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/664/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: get your hand on a good debugger like: http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You got it backwards; it should be

```
test_data.replace(...);
```

Also, you don't need `var` before the second assignment to "test_data"; just the first one.

Answer (score 3):

`replace` is undefined. It is not an object.

Use `replace` from the string prototype

```
"string".replace(//, "");
```

As you can see:

```
alert(String.prototype.replace)
```

Results in

```
function replace() {
    [native code]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `replace.test_data` by `test_data.replace`